# Apply a rotation matrix to xy coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, matrix, rotation

I have `xy` coordinates that represents a subject over a given space. It is referenced from another point and is therefore *off centre*. As in the `longitudinal` `axes` is not aligned along the `x-axis`.

The randomly generated `ellipse` below provides an indication of this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import scatter

xx = np.array([-0.51, 51.2])
yy = np.array([0.33, 51.6])
means = [xx.mean(), yy.mean()]  
stds = [xx.std() / 3, yy.std() / 3]
corr = 0.8         # correlation
covs = [[stds[0]**2          , stds[0]*stds[1]*corr], 
    [stds[0]*stds[1]*corr,           stds[1]**2]] 

m = np.random.multivariate_normal(means, covs, 1000).T
scatter(m[0], m[1])
```

To *straighten* the coordinates I was thinking of applying the vector to a `rotation matrix`.

Would something like this work?

```
angle = 65.
theta = (angle/180.) * np.pi

rotMatrix = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)], 
                     [np.sin(theta),  np.cos(theta)]])
```

This may also seem like a silly question but is there a way to determine if the resulting `vector` of `xy` coordinates is perpendicular? Or will you just have to play around with the `rotation angle`?

Comment: Please have a look at Edit 2 on my answer and let me know if it works for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sklearn.decomposition.PCA`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) (principal component analysis) with `n_components=2` to extract the smallest angle required to rotate the point cloud such that its major axis is horizontal.

#### Runnable example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

np.random.seed(1)

xx = np.array([-0.51, 51.2])
yy = np.array([0.33, 51.6])
means = [xx.mean(), yy.mean()]  
stds = [xx.std() / 3, yy.std() / 3]
corr = 0.8         # correlation
covs = [[stds[0]**2,       stds[0]*stds[1]*corr], 
        [stds[0]*stds[1]*corr, stds[1]**2]]

m = np.random.multivariate_normal(means, covs, 1000)

pca = PCA(2)

# This was in my first answer attempt: fit_transform works fine, but it randomly 
# flips (mirrors) points across one of the principal axes.
# m2 = pca.fit_transform(m)

# Workaround: get the rotation angle from the PCA components and manually 
# build the rotation matrix.

# Fit the PCA object, but do not transform the data
pca.fit(m)

# pca.components_ : array, shape (n_components, n_features)
# cos theta
ct = pca.components_[0, 0]
# sin theta
st = pca.components_[0, 1]

# One possible value of theta that lies in [0, pi]
t = np.arccos(ct)

# If t is in quadrant 1, rotate CLOCKwise by t
if ct > 0 and st > 0:
    t *= -1
# If t is in Q2, rotate COUNTERclockwise by the complement of theta
elif ct < 0 and st > 0:
    t = np.pi - t
# If t is in Q3, rotate CLOCKwise by the complement of theta
elif ct < 0 and st < 0:
    t = -(np.pi - t)
# If t is in Q4, rotate COUNTERclockwise by theta, i.e., do nothing
elif ct > 0 and st < 0:
    pass

# Manually build the ccw rotation matrix
rotmat = np.array([[np.cos(t), -np.sin(t)], 
                   [np.sin(t),  np.cos(t)]])

# Apply rotation to each row of m
m2 = (rotmat @ m.T).T

# Center the rotated point cloud at (0, 0)
m2 -= m2.mean(axis=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_kws = {'alpha': '0.75',
            'edgecolor': 'white',
            'linewidths': 0.75}
ax.scatter(m[:, 0], m[:, 1], **plot_kws)
ax.scatter(m2[:, 0], m2[:, 1], **plot_kws)
```

#### Output

[image]

#### Warning: `pca.fit_transform()` sometimes flips (mirrors) the point cloud

The principal components can randomly come out as either positive or negative. In some cases, your point cloud may appear flipped upside down or even mirrored across one of its principal axes. (To test this, change the random seed and re-run the code until you observe flipping.) There's an in-depth discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88880/does-the-sign-of-scores-or-of-loadings-in-pca-or-fa-have-a-meaning-may-i-revers) (based in R, but the math is relevant). To correct this, you'd have to replace the `fit_transform` line with manual flipping of one or both components' signs, then multiply the sign-flipped component matrix by the point cloud array.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Leimbigler. This is brilliant. I contemplated the orientation problem. It's not a huge issue as long as all the points have been rotated in the same direction. As in some points have been rotated 45 degrees, while other have been rotated 135 degrees. Can you confirm this? Does that make sense?

Comment: @Maxibon, my original code could randomly flip (mirror) the point cloud across one of the principal axes, in which case not every point would have rotated through the same angle. I have edited my answer to include a manual correction that should always rotate by at most 90 º, regardless of the original orientation of the point cloud.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed a very useful concept here is a linear transformation of a vector `v` performed by a matrix `A`. If you treat your scatter points as the tip of vectors originating from (0,0), then is very easy to rotate them any angle `theta`. A matrix that performs such rotation of `theta` would be

```
A = [[cos(theta) -sin(theta]
     [sin(theta)  cos(theta)]]
```

Evidently, when theta is 90 degrees this results into

```
A = [[ 0 1]
     [-1 0]]
```

And to apply the rotation you would only need to perform the matrix multiplication `w = A v`

With this, the current goal is to perform a matrix multiplication of the vectors stored in `m` with x,y tips as `m[0],m[1]`. The rotated vector are gonna be stored in `m2`. Below is the relevant code to do so. Note that I have transposed `m` for an easier computation of the matrix multiplication (performed with `@`) and that the rotation angle is 90 degress counterclockwise.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx = np.array([-0.51, 51.2])
yy = np.array([0.33, 51.6])
means = [xx.mean(), yy.mean()]  
stds = [xx.std() / 3, yy.std() / 3]
corr = 0.8         # correlation
covs = [[stds[0]**2          , stds[0]*stds[1]*corr], 
    [stds[0]*stds[1]*corr,           stds[1]**2]] 

m = np.random.multivariate_normal(means, covs, 1000).T
plt.scatter(m[0], m[1])

theta_deg = 90
theta_rad = np.deg2rad(theta_deg)
A = np.matrix([[np.cos(theta_rad), -np.sin(theta_rad)],
               [np.sin(theta_rad), np.cos(theta_rad)]])
m2 = np.zeros(m.T.shape)

for i,v in enumerate(m.T):
  w = A @ v.T
  m2[i] = w
m2 = m2.T

plt.scatter(m2[0], m2[1])
```

This leads to the rotated scatter plot:
[image]
You can be sure that the rotated version is exactly 90 degrees counterclockwise with the linear transformation.

**Edit**

To find the rotation angle you need to apply in order for the scatter plot to be aligned with the x axis a good approach is to find the linear approximation of the scattered data with `numpy.polyfit`. This yields to a linear function by providing the `slope` and the intercept of the y axis `b`. Then get the rotation angle with the `arctan` function of the slope and compute the transformation matrix as before. You can do this by adding the following part to the code

```
slope, b = np.polyfit(m[1], m[0], 1)
x = np.arange(min(m[0]), max(m[0]), 1)
y_line = slope*x + b
plt.plot(x, y_line, color='r')
theta_rad = -np.arctan(slope)
```

And result to the plot you were seeking
[image]

**Edit 2**

Because @Peter Leimbigler pointed out that `numpy.polyfit` does not find the correct global direction of the scattered data, I have thought that you can get the average slope by averaging the `x` and `y` parts of the data. This is to find another slope, called `slope2` (depicted in green now) to apply the rotation. So simply,

```
slope, b = np.polyfit(m[1], m[0], 1)
x = np.arange(min(m[0]), max(m[0]), 1)
y_line = slope*x + b
slope2 = np.mean(m[1])/np.mean(m[0])
y_line2 = slope2*x + b
plt.plot(x, y_line, color='r')
plt.plot(x, y_line2, color='g')
theta_rad = -np.arctan(slope2)
```

And by applying the linear transformation with the rotation matrix you get
[image]

Comment: So how do you know you need `-45°` rotation and not say `-47°`? This is what the question asks for iiuc.

Comment: Done, have a look at it please and let me know if you think is better now :)

Comment: Yep, it seems to answer the question now.

Comment: `np.polyfit` minimizes squared error **in y**, not the squared error perpendicular to the fitted line, which is what PCA effectively minimizes. As a result, the `polyfit` approach often *under*estimates the required clockwise rotation angle. For example, run with `np.random.seed(1234)`. To the human eye, the resulting rotation is not enough.

Comment: Fair enough. Did you downvoted because of this though?

Comment: Please have a look at my edit and let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @b-fg. I thought I accepted the previous answer sorry.

Comment: Fair enough, even though I think mine is cleaner!

Comment: @b-fg, about Edit 2: I think the `slope2` approach only works if the point cloud's major axis happens to point at the origin (for which there is no reason to expect). For example, re-running the example data with `xx = np.array([9.51, 61.2])` and `yy = np.array([0.33, 51.6])` (i.e., the point cloud's major axis still has a slope of ~1.0, but has been shifted right by 10 units) produces an incorrect `slope2`.

Comment: That's right, but since it was not the case of the original post I thought it was a good approach for this test case.

Comment: Instead of a line, one could [fit an ellipse](http://nicky.vanforeest.com/misc/fitEllipse/fitEllipse.html). I think this would also solve the problem of the axis not necessarily pointing to the origin as commented by @PeterLeimbigler.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, fitting an ellipse might work, but I expect that linked approach to fail on this case of a point cloud whose density is highest in the middle and falls off at the edges. That ellipse-fitting code is designed for points that already lie roughly along an elliptical curve, not a cluster of points whose overall shape is elliptical.

Comment: One could fit a "total least squares" or "orthogonal least squares" line to the data ([using scipy.odr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html)), but PCA (or SVD) already does exactly that, and to my knowledge is the most correct and natural solution to the problem of finding the angle between the major axis of an elliptical point cloud and a feature-space axis (e.g., +x axis).

Answer (score 0):

If the slope of the two lines multiplied together is equal to -1 than they are perpendicular.
The other case this is true, is when one slope is 0 and the other is undefined (a perfectly horizontal line and a perfectly vertical line).